# How to add preventDefault in a function where event is not the param

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a html part of my angularjs app :

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRa8VRM5d5c" ng-click="createTab('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRa8VRM5d5c');" title="youtube">youtube</a>
```

and in controller :

```
$rootScope.createTab = function(url) {
    if (isExtension !== undefined) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: (url)});
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
}
```

How to add the support of preventDefault ? 'e' is not defined, but i need 'e' , and i have already a param to pass... It's a chrome app but it's also available like a mini-website. I want links opened in a new tab, even if we are not on chrome.

Comment: <button ng-click="clickMe($event)">Event</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in [`$event` from the markup](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) and use it in your handler.

```
ng-click="createTab('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRa8VRM5d5c', $event);"
```

And

```
$rootScope.createTab = function(url, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isExtension !== undefined) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: (url)});
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
}
```

> $event - Directives like ngClick and ngFocus expose a $event object within the scope of that expression.